# What is winansi?

Tags: unicode, encoding

I can't find a wikipage or anthing :(. It's an encoding like unicode right? So it has it's  own mapping of code points to characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that in most cases, someone saying "Win ANSI" or "Windows ANSI code page" is talking about the [Windows-1252 character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Calling it "ANSI" is a misnomer, as pointed out in that article.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes (in MSDN documentation for WinAPI calls) it is just a name for the current Windows system encoding, which may or may not be 1252.